# Как обьявить аргумент fields в Django?

Tags: python, django

```py
class createListing(forms.ModelForm):
    title = forms.CharField(label= "Title", max_length = 32)
    description = forms.CharField(label= "Description", max_length = 499)
    price = forms.IntegerField(label = "Price")
    
    class Meta(forms.ModelForm):
        model = Category
        fields = "__all__"
```

Вот сама ошибка:

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Creating a ModelForm without either the 'fields' attribute or the 'exclude' attribute is prohibited; form createListing needs updating.

UPD: Решил проблему: надо было перезапустить сервер

Comment: Миграции сделали?

Comment: да, я сделал миграции

Answer (score 0):

Надо было перезапустить сервер после миграций